# repaint() does not call paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, graphics, repaint

please help me understand why repaint() won't call paintComponent() *if called from inside an* actionPerformed() method. I 've tried everything but i still don't get it. I've ultra simplified the code but the problem remains.
Here's the code:

the JPanel's paintComponent():

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
    super.paintComponent(gr);

    System.out.println("paint");        
}
```

the ActionListener (which is the panel) is registered to a Timer with:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    repaint();
    System.out.println("repaint");
}
```

I also added a Mouse Listener to the panel. Here is the method:

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    repaint();  
    System.out.println("repaint");
}
```

if I press the mouse twice it prints (as expected)

```
paint
repaint
paint
repaint
```

but if i call timer.start() it prints

```
repaint
repaint
repaint
repaint
```

Any ideas?

thanks

**EDIT:** I also added this line to the actionPerformed() method:

```
setBackground(Color.RED);
```

so that it actually makes a change to the panel, but the color does not change, and i get the same output.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of passive painting and the `RepaintManager` - The `RepaintManager` is making decisions about what should be painted and may decide to schedule paint events at a later time or combine them as it sees fit.  Because the mouse causes a change in the system graphics, it tends to generate repaint requests more reliably.  As to your `Timer`, we'd need to see much more context before a clear conclusion could be made ... i.e. are you requesting a `repaint` on the same instance of the same object

Comment: @ MadProgrammer i'm new to JAVA so apologies if i'm wrong,  but the timer is instansiated inside this JPanel's constructor. Also there are no other  instances of the panel (nor another panel). The snipets are the final result after a long way of searxhing what is going on. The initial paintComponent() and actionPerformed() methods did actually change the panel.

Comment: I did a really quick test and it works fine for me, each time the `Timer` clicks,  It calls `repaint` which then generates a "painting" message - maybe you should consider providing a runnable example which reliably reproduces your problem

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).